# why Value coming as "i=2" instead of 2

Tags: c#, dictionary

In below code why Value coming as "i=2" instead of 2.

[image]

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<object>>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
        {
            if (dictionary.Keys.Contains("Key1"))
            {
                dictionary["Key1"].Add(new { i });
            }
            else
            {
                dictionary.Add("Key1", new List<object> { i});
            }
        }
```

Comment: `new { i }` creates a new object of an anonymous type with one property named `i` (set to the value of the variable `i`), so that's what you get. If you just wanted to add `i`, you should have written `.Add(i)`.

Comment: Consider changing `List<object>` to `List<int>` so that the compiler can give you more useful error messages. Also, don't use `Keys.Contains`. Instead use `TryGetValue`.

Comment: To help you visualise your mistake, `new { i }` is actually shorthand for `new { i = i }`.

Comment: @mjwills As someone not up to date on C#, that is a surprising shorthand. Is it commonly used?

Comment: @Borgleader Sure. A new object is created and i is the key with the value of 2. The key of the array containing the object has the index of 1.

Comment: @Borgleader: consider `from x in ... let CustomerID = ... let Count = ... select new { CustomerID, Count }`. Being forced to duplicate the names (`new { CustomerID = CustomerID, ...`) does not make for easier reading. Of course, like all syntactic sugar, sometimes it rots your teeth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite some problems with your code. First, is the 'strange' output you see. Your `new { i }` created a new anonymous type with a property `i` with value `2` (the `i` from the property name is inferred from the variable name. It is equal to `new { i = i }`).

I would propose to use this:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<object>>();

for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
{
    if (!dictionary.TryGetValue("Key1", out List<object> list))
    {
        list = new List<object>();
        dictionary["Key1"] = list;
    }

    list.Add(i);
}
```